# How to add mysites mail to whitelist?

Tags: php, email, email-spam

Currently I am developing a website.In this I have the option to send invittion.When I send the Invitation it going to spam folder.How can I send my site's  mails to Inbox.Whether I nedd the trafic to add into whitelist?Or is there anyother way to make to directly send the email to Inbox.My site is developed in PHP......Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post the code for your PHP mail script, especially the headers.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's due to how you are setting your headers. To ease the pain of sending emails, I generally recommend [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The from and reply-to addresses should match the server domain name, or even better, send the mail from the server specified by your domain's MX record.